# IntelliJ full screen, really

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to run `IntelliJ Idea` in a true full screen mode on a MAC?

**No toolbars, no side bars, no buttons, just code.**

If it is possible please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the `View` menu by disabling the following items:

[image: view]

Double clicking on the editor tab will hide all the open tool windows (second double click will restore them).

It's also possible to disable editor tabs in `Preferences` | `Editor` | `Editor Tabs`.